# use result of data from database to App.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, pg

Ive got this code so far on a pg.js ... i want to use the result  of {rows} ... in my App.js.. i tryed evreything ... I cant get it to work I need help. thanks

```
const {Client} = require('pg');

const client = new Client({
 ...
    ssl: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
});



async function execute(){

    client.connect()
        .then(() => console.log("connected to server"))
    const {rows} = await  client.query('select * from ggl_trends')
    console.table(rows)

}

execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to send the queries once the connection is up.

```js
async function execute() {
  await client.connect()
  console.log('Connected to server')
  const { rows } = await client.query('select * from ggl_trends')
  console.table(rows)
}
```

Comment: I try to put in a  ... class ... extends React.Component {...
but i gives me alot of problems 

TypeError: net.Socket is not a constructor

constructor(config) {
  16 |   super()
  17 |   config = config || {}
> 18 |   this.stream = config.stream || new net.Socket()
     | ^  19 |   this._keepAlive = config.keepAlive
  20 |   this._keepAliveInitialDelayMillis = config.keepAliveInitialDelayMillis
  21 |   this.lastBuffer = false

Comment: @IgorSilva Not sure if I understand. The code that talks to the database should be in the backend.

Comment: const {Client} = require('pg'); use pg 

async function execute(){

    client.connect()
        .then(() => console.log("connected to server"))
    const {rows} = await  client.query('select * from ggl_trends')
    console.table(rows)

} this get the data to const {rows} ... now i want to display that in my App.js